# Change DPI with Javascript Google Maps Api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, printing, dpi

I need to create a 80x80cm (or 33inchx33inch) map with Google Maps. This map will be printed and exhibited, so the higher DPI the better. Actually, in printing, a 300DPI is the minimum.

Now, I'm using the Javascript API in order to create the map I want :
- change the mapOptions with an array of styles with various colors
- add a Transit Overlay in order to have the map of the urban trains added over the map (see this aautar.digital-radiation.com/blog/?p=3761)
- add polygons as a link to KML URL to one of my maps

If you want to see the result : http://www.tellnet.fr/blog/test.html (it's very long to download since it's a 5000x5000 picture).

The problem is that, at the Scale level I want (with not too many details), the big picture I get is a 5000x5000, which gives a 150DPI only printable file.

To obtain a 10000x10000 picture as I would to print a 80x80cm map at 300 DPI, I need to :
- either my map zoom once, but then I've got soooo many details, that will be printed super tiny
- or change the DPI of the map, asking Google Maps to double it.

*It would basically give me the same map at the same scale, but with thinner lines and texts (making a 10000x10000 pictures).*

I know this is possible with the static maps Api, change the Scale value to 2 (see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=fr#scale_values).

The problem is that, this is the **static** maps API, so please can someone tell me if :
- it's either possible to do all the above things with the static API
- or change the "scale" value (ie the DPI value) with the Javascript API.

I also tried to change the meta viewport value, but this only works with mobile devices... (I searched for all solutions, now I'm blocked!)

Comment: What you need to do is to create a custom tile layer with a tile size of 128 x 128, (instead of the default 256 x 256). The problem would be how to get the tiles from the base map and use them on your custom layer because the V3 of the API does not offer access to the base maps. I'll give this some more thought and I'll post a reply if I come up with something.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Marcelo! I'm still on it, and if you have anything, I will be pleased.

Comment: Hello Marcelo, did you have any idea since then? Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no regular way to access the base maps. At some point this was reported as a bug, but you can read the comments by members of the maps team on this thread: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3635#c2